# Does Springfox 2.7.0 supports Spring 3.1.0

Tags: spring, swagger, springfox

Currently my application is running in spring 3.1.0. I have planned to implement swagger in it. Please advise me which springfox runs in spring 3.1.0

Comment: I believe the minimum version ever supported was 3.2+. That was the minimum version that was supported up until v2.5 of springfox.

Comment: Thanks alot Dilip. I think I need to upgrade the spring first. Can I know which spring is compatible with latest SpringFox?

Comment: 4.3.8 is the tested version

Comment: Thank you Dilip. Then I will upgrade with 4.3.8